# How to instantiate a Class/Bean in Spring MVC by request?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control

First of all I'm quite new to Springframwork.

Let's say I have a controller in Spring-MVC:

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/addfoo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void addRequest(          
        @RequestParam(value="rq_param", required=true) String param){

        foo.setValue(param);    
        fooService.addFoo(foo);                     
    }
}
```

I need to add Foo into a database. But before I need to set a value. This should happen when a certain request comes in (from elsewhere).

Here's my Service:

```
@Service
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    @Autowired
    private FooDAO fooDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void addFoo(Foo foo) {
        fooDAO.addFoo(foo);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
```

I'm quite sure that I've a made a basic mistake due to my lack of knowledge about IoC...

Thanks!

Comment: Does `Foo` has `@Service` annotation?

Comment: As you have 2 autowired injections, you should comment out one/two of them in order to narrow down the error. Wild guess: it might be foo (the simpler item).

Comment: Foo is a POJO and not a service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should inject the Foo.  It looks like a model object to me, not an interface-based service or controller.

You should create one using new when the request comes in, outside of Spring's control.  You want to bind the value from the request parameter into the new Foo object and persist it.

Every object in a Spring project need not be under the control of the bean factory.

Usually you see calls to new for objects within method scope.  They're usually POJO model objects that don't have interfaces.  Your cases seems to be one of them to me.

Comment: The way you propose works. I knew that before. But I often read that using the new-keyword isn't a good practice, so I would like to avoid it (if possible).

Comment: No, it's exactly the right thing in this case.  All your beans need not be under Spring's control.  Know the rules, know the exceptions.  Dogma without thought is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="service,controllers,dao"></context:component-scan>
```

edit it in your servlet.xml after dtd.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

this one in your web.xml file.

for dao u should add an annotation @Repository

may be i am wrong.. but try this one..